# How to add CSS if element has 2 chlids, and another element if has 3 childs?

Tags: html, css

I want to transfom: translateY(200%) if it has 2 childs, and translateY(300%) if it has 3 childs.
How can i do this?

Comment: Please share your code and what you have tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution,

```
 .product-status:nth-last-child(n + 3),
      .product-status:nth-last-child(n + 3)~* {
        transform: translateY(300%)!important;
    }
    .product-status:nth-last-child(n + 2),
      .product-status:nth-last-child(n + 2)~* {
        transform: translateY(150%);
    }
```

That solves the problem